# get java.lang.ArrayStoreException on Springboot and ehcache

Tags: java, spring-boot, ehcache

I have a method that calls a webservice and for same input arguments, I want the result to be cached. So, here is what i did so far:
The main class:

```
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.cache.CacheManager;
import org.springframework.cache.annotation.EnableCaching;
import org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheCacheManager;
import org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;

@EnableCaching
@ComponentScan
@SpringBootApplication
public class AccServer extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

   @Bean
   public CacheManager cacheManager() {
      return new EhCacheCacheManager(ehCacheCacheManager().getObject());
   }

   @Bean
   public EhCacheManagerFactoryBean ehCacheCacheManager() {
      EhCacheManagerFactoryBean cmfb = new EhCacheManagerFactoryBean();
      cmfb.setConfigLocation(new ClassPathResource("ehcache.xml"));
      cmfb.setShared(true);
      return cmfb;
   }

}
```

Method to cache:

```
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.cache.annotation.Cacheable;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class SomeClass implements ISomeClass {

   @Override
   @Cacheable("acc")
   public List<Integer> trs() {
      return webSrv.trs();
   }

}
```

ehcache.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ehcache xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://ehcache.org/ehcache.xsd" updateCheck="false">
    <diskStore path="java.io.tmpdir" />
    <cache name="acc" maxElementsInMemory="100" eternal="false" timeToIdleSeconds="120" timeToLiveSeconds="120" overflowToDisk="true" maxElementsOnDisk="10000000" diskPersistent="false" diskExpiryThreadIntervalSeconds="120" memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU" />
</ehcache>
```

And I get:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayStoreException: sun.reflect.annotation.TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseClassArray(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseArray(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseMemberValue(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotation2(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations2(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.createAnnotationData(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.annotationData(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.createAnnotationData(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.annotationData(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getAnnotation(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.cache.annotation.SpringCacheAnnotationParser.getAnnotations(SpringCacheAnnotationParser.java:201)
    at org.springframework.cache.annotation.SpringCacheAnnotationParser.parseCacheAnnotations(SpringCacheAnnotationParser.java:64)
    at org.springframework.cache.annotation.SpringCacheAnnotationParser.parseCacheAnnotations(SpringCacheAnnotationParser.java:52)
    at org.springframework.cache.annotation.AnnotationCacheOperationSource$1.getCacheOperations(AnnotationCacheOperationSource.java:113)
    at org.springframework.cache.annotation.AnnotationCacheOperationSource.determineCacheOperations(AnnotationCacheOperationSource.java:142)
    at org.springframework.cache.annotation.AnnotationCacheOperationSource.findCacheOperations(AnnotationCacheOperationSource.java:110)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.AbstractFallbackCacheOperationSource.computeCacheOperations(AbstractFallbackCacheOperationSource.java:142)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.AbstractFallbackCacheOperationSource.getCacheOperations(AbstractFallbackCacheOperationSource.java:97)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheOperationSourcePointcut.matches(CacheOperationSourcePointcut.java:39)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.canApply(AopUtils.java:211)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.canApply(AopUtils.java:248)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.findAdvisorsThatCanApply(AopUtils.java:280)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findAdvisorsThatCanApply(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:118)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findEligibleAdvisors(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:88)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.getAdvicesAndAdvisorsForBean(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:69)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.wrapIfNecessary(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:346)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessAfterInitialization(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:422)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1583)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
    ... 135 more
```

I also use `@Cacheable("acc")` annotation for the method which should be cached for the result.
Any answers would be appreciated.

Comment: Add the code where you have got @Cacheable("acc") and @CachePut

Comment: @javaguy added.

Comment: I need the whole class with @Cacheput  as well or any other operations in that class with caching, better add the whole class, it would be easy to find

Comment: @javaguy I just did.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with the `@Cacheable` `trs()` method (of your `@Service` `SomeClass` class) which is NOT returning `List<Integer>` object because of which you are getting `sun.reflect.annotation.TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy` exception.

You need to ensure that `trs()` is returning the `List<Integer>` object.

Comment: I don't think so, cause changing the return clause to "return new ArrayList<Intger>()" still gives the same exception.

Comment: And also I get this exception in application startup!!

Comment: Can you add the code for webSrv.trs() method so that I can suggest the return type to be used for Service method to avoid this exception ?

Comment: sure, but what is very astonishing to me is that by removing the `@cacheable` annotation from entire project methods, I still get this exception.

Comment: That's what I am saying in my answer since some time, your return type declared in public List<Integer> trs() is different from what is being returned by return webSrv.trs();

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to fellows how contributed on this question, finally after long time of debugging, I just found that there is need for excluding two dependencies from project, so that it becomes:

```
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-actuator</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
```

Answer (score 0):

That exception means something attempted to do a lookup on an annotation that's not present on the classpath. Unfortunately, the JDK isn't telling us much about it but I think we've improved the error message in recent version of the framework (and therefore boot).

You could also add a breakpoint in the faulty code and it will tell you what it's trying to resolve. That should give you a hint of what the missing annotation is. Most of the time, this isn't strictly related to the component that does the lookup (i.e. it might very well be unrelated to caching). If you share a sample app, we could easily figure it out.